# Rotate text in Plain Tex table (Using OPMAC) across several rows

Tags: tables, pdftex, opmac

I'm trying reproduce this table (shown in the image) using Plain Tex and using the OPmac package for creating tables.

I have no idea how to include the rotated text "have been" (with the left brace) that crosses multiple rows.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Look at the example on the OPMAC site: http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#rotsimple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\pdfsave` and `\pdfrestore` primitives from pdfTeX and `\pdfrotate` macro from OPmac. The example below uses fixed text saved to the box `\hbeenbox`. You can modify this macro for your needs.

```
\input opmac

\newbox\hbeenbox
\setbox\hbeenbox=\hbox to0pt{\hss\kern1ex \vtop to0pt{\vss
    \halign{\hfil#\hfil\cr
    $\underbrace{\kern3\baselineskip}$\cr \typosize[8/] have been\cr}}\hss
}
\def\havebeen{\ \pdfsave\pdfrotate{90}{\copy\hbeenbox}\pdfrestore}

\centerline{Perfect Tense (may have)}
\smallskip
\hfil\table{lc|lc}{
fu-erim, I may        &          & fu-erimus, we may   &          \cr
fu-erist, thoy mayst  &\havebeen & fu-eritis, ye may   &\havebeen \cr
fu-erit, he may       &          & fu erint, they may  &          \cr
}

\bye
```

Note that OpTeX is newer than OPmac and it does the same result for this example. I recommend to use OpTeX instead OPmac. You will have no problems with accents (used in your example) with OpTeX, because it uses Unicode and you can write the accented letters directly. On the other hand, you need to load special additional macro files for such accents when you are using only pdfTeX.